# Prevent Hibernate internal logging

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, log4j

We are using

```
log4j.appender.file1.Threshold=INFO
```

With this approach , the Database password is also getting printed in the log file as below.

```
01 Jul 2016 13:08:22 INFO org.hibernate.connection.DrivermanagerConnectionProvider-connection properties:{user=abc,password=xyz,release_mode=on_close
```

We wanted to prevent this line from printing in the log file as it is not good practice.

I tried replacing INFO with WARN but this is not giving any log information at INFO level.

Please help

Comment: Do you want to only hide that specific line or all log output from hibernate? You can define a logger for `org.hibernate.connection.DrivermanagerConnectionProvider` in the log4j config and mute it. That will hide all log output from that class, though. I don't know hibernate but I wonder if there is some kind of konfiguration key that hides that specific line from being output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With log4j you can setup the logging level specifically to the class or package you want. In this case I suggest you setup
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.connection=WARN, file1`